# php gathering mysql result in multi table same column

Tags: php, mysql

I break down my database into 4 tables. each one is the same structure.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dba` WHERE domain>= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(domain) * RAND()) FROM `dba` ) ORDER BY domain LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $domain = $list["domain"];
    echo $domain;
    }
```

now the result from sql_query only return one row.
how to i show it all from 4 table.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM `dba` WHERE domain>= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(domain) * RAND()) FROM `dba` ) ORDER BY domain LIMIT 1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM `dbb` WHERE domain>= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(domain) * RAND()) FROM `dbb` ) ORDER BY domain LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM `dbc` WHERE domain>= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(domain) * RAND()) FROM `dbc` ) ORDER BY domain LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM `dbd` WHERE domain>= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(domain) * RAND()) FROM `dbd` ) ORDER BY domain LIMIT 1
```